# make a layout just fits the width when it's in a HorizonrtalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal `LinearLayout` that contains bunch of vertical `Linearlayouts`, each one of these vertical Layouts supposed to fit only 25% of the horizontal layout, so it can only contains four ones, so, i want to add a `HorizonrtalScrollView` to contain the rest of the vertical layouts when it's number is more than four,

i set the `WeightSum` of the horizontal layout as four so that any vertical layout will take a weight as one, and that will make it fits only 25% of the horizontal layout. everything is ok before adding the `HorizonrtalScrollView`, consider the following figure (the vertical layouts is the **Green** colored):

[image]

But when adding the `HorizonrtalScrollView` :

[image]

I considered setting the horizontal layout as `WrapContent` and `FillParent` but the same result, although the same when setting `HorizonrtalScrollView` as `WrapContent` and `FillParent` .

**XML code:**

```
      <HorizontalScrollView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <LinearLayout 
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:orientation="horizontal"
                       android:weightSum="4" >

        <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/innerVer1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/icon1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/ac_overlay"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:tag="normal" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/icon2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/ac_overlay"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:tag="normal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/innerVer1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/icon1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/ac_overlay"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:tag="normal" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/icon2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/ac_overlay"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:tag="normal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: ru sure ur horizotal view itself causing the issue ?. means if u dont that every thing seen properly.

Comment: what can cause the issue if it's not

Comment: no tried out whole xml part it has lots of issues width and height.

Comment: can u post ur graphical snap shot of the xml.

Comment: @sush no the problem stills the same

Comment: did u got proper xml graph view by the after setting everything to fill parent

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried changing Linear layout width attribute to wrap content.

Answer (score 0):

change your horizontal view tags attributes with this below

```
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

most important attribute

```
                android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: these changes to the horizontal layout ? i made it to the horizontal layout and nothing changed

Comment: thats i asked u below ur question is it working fine ? so change all ur 0dp to fill_parent and wrap_content also to fill_parent.